# How to enlarge imshow image inside subplot?

Tags: matplotlib

```
def plot_image(image):
    plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray", interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")



# # What is a Convolution?

# In[3]:


import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image

# Load sample images
china = load_sample_image("china.jpg") / 255
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg") / 255
images = np.array([china, flower])
batch_size, height, width, channels = images.shape

# Create 2 filters
filters = np.zeros(shape=(7, 7, channels, 2), dtype=np.float32)
filters[:, 3, :, 0] = 1  # vertical line
filters[3, :, :, 1] = 1  # horizontal line

outputs = tf.nn.conv2d(images, filters, strides=1, padding="SAME")


for image_index in (0, 1):
    for feature_map_index in (0, 1):
        plt.subplot(2, 2, image_index * 2 + feature_map_index + 1)
        plot_image(outputs[image_index, :, :, feature_map_index])

plt.show()
```

I tried using `plt.figure(figsize=(100,100))` (not sure what the dimension is or what it means..)  It doesn't work anyway..

Comment: where did you put the `plt.figure` call? works fine for me

Comment: @flippo before the for loop (at the end) after the `conv2d`

Comment: that's weird, it works fine within jupyter, maybe you're using a gui backend and the image is being scaled to the window size

Comment: maybe because, mine outputs image even before `plt.show()` ?

Comment: which matplotlib backend are you using?

Comment: Matplotlib has documentation.  Can you truly not parse what figsize means?

Comment: @JodyKlymak : I guess I'm having trouble with `figure, plot, subplots`  more than `figsize`

Comment: @filippo 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'